# Detection of unmodeled dependence

Tags: correlation, causality, independence, bernoulli-distribution, anomaly-detection

Given 2 joint groups Bernoulli trials: $X_i \sim p_i$ and $Y_i \sim q_i$, where $(X_i, Y_i)$ are binary outcomes of the $i$-th experiment, and $(p_i, q_i)$ are the probabilities of $X_i=1$ and $Y_i=1$ respectively. $p_i$ and $q_i$ are functions of a random variable $r_i$.

In the $i$-th experiment, $p_i$ and $q_i$ are correlated, because they share the same cause $r_i$. Consequently, $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are correlated via $p_i$ and $q_i$.

Now, I suspect $X_i$ and $Y_i$ have direct causal relation in-between. Given a large amount of experiment outcomes $\{(X_i, Y_i)\}$, is there a statistical test to detect such extra dependence between $X_i$ and $Y_i$?

Comment: Causality cannot be proven in observational studies. You can only prove that A has statistical relationship with B. To prove causality you need to stage a randomized controlled experiment, to make sure that there are no undetected confouders in the picture.